# AngularJS' reverse OrderBy in ng-repeat is returning not reversed links

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

So, I've just published an AngularJS job board in which the submitted data is saved as JSON in a file and it feeds the board. In ng-repeat I set to OrderBy:'-time', which returns the latest entry at the top of the list, but if you see the links for each entry, it remains the original, being 0 the oldest one, but it keeps being the top one. How to solve this? I want to reverse not only the list, but links should stick to their relative item.

```
<div class="card panel panel-default" ng-repeat="app in openings | filter:query | orderBy:'-time'">
    <a class="panel-body" href="#/job/{{$index}}">
        <div class="inner">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{app.job}}</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>{{app.type}}</li>
                <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>{{app.company}}</li>
                <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>{{app.city}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

In this case, `{{$index}}` is not being reversed along with the rest of the information.

You may see the job board [here](https://paulogabriel.me/extranet/labs/angularjs-jobboard/#/). Github link [here](https://github.com/paulogabriel/angularjs-jobboard).

Thank you!

Comment: You should try to narrow down the problem to 1 or 2 short snippets of code that you can post here. This question will stop being useful if the links die. Also, I don't think many readers will follow the link and read the code in the repository. Other clearer questions will win for our time

Comment: @slezica updated the question.

Comment: $index will show you the position. So the first one will always be 0, as expected. Maybe you need to use "Id" or something similar of your object model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why `$index` is finding the wrong element

`$index` will show you the index in the `ng-repeat` list, *not* the index in the `list.json` object.

What you *want* is a unique reference to an item in `list.json`.

### Why you (currently) want an index to an array

Currently your routing looks like this:

```
.when('/job/:id',{
    controller: 'JobController',
    templateUrl: 'views/opening.html'
})
```

So, each job is identified by an `id`.

You currently produce this route by binding `$index`:

```
<a class="panel-body" href="#/job/{{$index}}">
```

Your `id` is used as an index in an array called `data`:

```
$scope.detail = data[$routeParams.id];
```

`data` is an array that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "job": "Full Stack Front-end Developer",
    "company": "Zinga",
    "city": "Tokyo",
    "category": "Design",
    "type": "Freelance",
    "description": "Em documentos utilizados para testes, este tipo de texto \u00e9 utilizado para evitar que as pessoas foquem a aten\u00e7\u00e3o no texto e se concentrem nos aspectos visuais.",
    "time": "2016-03-23T23:18:46Z"
},
```

### The real problem

The item upon which your `ng-repeat` acts is *not* the original array `data`.

Thus your `ng-repeat` lacks the positional information that would enable you to point to things in `data`.

### Solution

You need a better unique index into `data`.

For example, if `job`+`company` constituted a "unique" index (it *probably* doesn't), then you could change your routing like this:

```
.when('/job/:job/:company'

var matches = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.job === $routeParams.job
    && item.company === $routeParams.company;
});
var firstMatch = matches[0];
$scope.detail = firstMatch;
```

Your Angular binding would have to look like this:

#### Alternative solution

I suspect there is no unique index available in your current object structure.

I recommend attaching a unique UUID to each item in `data`:

```
[
{
    "job": "Full Stack Front-end Developer",
    "company": "Zinga",
    "city": "Tokyo",
    "category": "Design",
    "type": "Freelance",
    "description": "Em documentos utilizados para testes, este tipo de texto \u00e9 utilizado para evitar que as pessoas foquem a aten\u00e7\u00e3o no texto e se concentrem nos aspectos visuais.",
    "time": "2016-03-23T23:18:46Z",
    "id": "51e6e313-fc64-4d1d-95d4-60af9fda2019"
},
```

*Now* you can use the `id` property upon any element in `data`.

As before, you could use just `id` in your routing:

```
.when('/job/:id'
```

But `id` would *not* be an index into an array; you would need to filter `data` on that criterion:

```
var matches = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id === $routeParams.id;
});
var firstMatch = matches[0];
$scope.detail = firstMatch;
```

Finally: your Angular binding would have to look like this:

```
<a class="panel-body" href="#/job/{{app.id}}">
```

Comment: Astonishing response! Thank you for taking your time to do this real lesson. I'll go thru it and fix it. Thank you again!

Comment: for some reason I'm failing to actually filter data as you mentioned: `return item.id === $routeParams.id;` ... The repeat does give the item that custom id, but it doesn't return the actual data once the link is accessed. I've made a copy of the board [here](https://paulogabriel.me/extranet/labs/angularjs-jobboard2/#/) and the script is [here](https://paulogabriel.me/extranet/labs/angularjs-jobboard2/js/script.js). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PauloGabriel ah, my bad. Forgot that `Array.prototype.filter` returns a list.

I've updated my answer.

Also, [a pull request](https://github.com/paulogabriel/angularjs-jobboard/pull/1) for your specific case, since I got it working locally.

Comment: sweet! It's working now. I've [updated the code](https://paulogabriel.me/extranet/labs/angularjs-jobboard/#/) with your solution (I'm kinda new to Github, and I think I didn't accept your pull request by mistake). Anyways, I'm really thankful to you.